# How can I tell prettier to only prettify --staged files?

Tags: javascript, package.json, prettier

I was using `pretty-quick`, but it was prettifying all my `node_modules`.

I've got prettier doing everything I'd like it to. 
It prettifies `js`, `scss`, and it only prettifies the files I've asked it to.

Now that I've prettified all my files, on future commits I'd only like prettifier to run on the files where changes have been made.

pretty-quick allows you to run `--staged` to only prettify the files with changes.

How can I tell prettier to only prettify `--staged` files?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with `lint-staged`

`yarn add husky lint-staged prettier --dev`

```
"scripts": {
    "precommit": "lint-staged"
},
"lint-staged": {
  "*.js": [
    "prettier --write"
  ],
  "*.scss": [
    "prettier --write"
  ]

}
```

Now, you're precommit hook will only run through the changed files prior to commit. 
Or if you don't need a precommit hook, skip husky, and just create a script in your package.json